# Why didn't Korean rulers ever use the title 황제 (皇帝) until the Korean Empire in the late 19th century?

Tags: etymology, history-of-korean

Ever since *Qin Shi Huangdi* ("First Huangdi of the Qin") made up the title 皇帝 (*huangdi*), Vietnamese and Japanese rulers quite consistently claimed to be "emperors" as well. The Japanese made up their own title, 天皇 (*tennō*), and the Vietnamese proclaimed that their land was ruled by their own *huangdi* with the poem [*The Southern Land's Mountains and Rivers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nam_qu%E1%BB%91c_s%C6%A1n_h%C3%A0). Korean rulers seem to have been conspicuous exceptions, given that they only started to use 황제 with the establishment of the westernized Korean Empire, following Japan's footsteps; before then, they only used the title 왕/王 (*wang*) which had long been demoted to a princely nobility title elsewhere.

Was there any linguistic or historical reason for this? I feel like this is probably the only place I can ask this question because I doubt there's anybody with adequate knowledge of the Korean language on History Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, they did. It's called 외왕내제(外王內帝), which means 'Emperor at home, king abroad'. Since it will be too much historic rather than linguistic to explain about that system here, I think you can start ['Emperor at home, king abroad'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_at_home,_king_abroad) and ['Korean imperial titles'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_imperial_titles) articles in Wikipedia.